Watermark allocated per Chapter or Section, not per page
I have taken a look at the draftmark, and draftwatermark packages (draftwatermark is more recently updated so will use it for the example), but cannot find the use case I need/want:
I want to apply a watermark to specific sections, without having to specify the page numbers, as it is tedious to have to re-work the page numbers every time I alter the document.
As an example, I am working on a document where the abstract will be completed last. I am using lorem ipsum to fill the space, but wish to make it clear that this is a draft that will be altered later. Similarly Appendix A is an incomplete document and should be labelled as draft also.
MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    %
    \include{./abstract}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
    \include{./introduction}
    \include{./literature_study}
    \include{./conclusion}
    \appendix
    \include{./appendix_A}
\end{document}

where, for this example, each \include{} file can be regarded as consisting of \lipsum. In this example the watermark appears on every single page. I want the watermark to only appear for the abstract section, irrespective if it is moved up or down in the order, or if pages come before it - say, for example, I decide to add acknowledgements before the abstract. Same behavior for the appendix.
It is a very large document, with many \include statements, so reworking that structure is not a feasible solution. I have tried adding the package to the individual .tex files, but this returns an error as all packages need to be loaded in the preamble.
Bonus: If possible to add draft watermarks even on the \section level, say for example a part of the literature study I am not satisfied with yet, that would be neat.
Proof of Research: The Closest Question I found to mine - Unfortunately does not answer the question I have

You could use a hook as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/724591/36296 and remove the hook at the end of the section
